# Troubleshooting Xbox Kinect 360

Tags: kinect

I recently got **libfreenect** running on my mac and was able to test out `freenect-glpclview` which uses some of the 3D capabilities of the depth sensor.

I noticed that the Kinect would only respond / pick up movement that happened within a range of about 3-6 inches in front of the sensor.

I thought this may be because the lights where on so I turned them off. It seemed to get a little better but it still only "works" if something is block the sensor almost completely.

Does anyone know if this is something that can be solved? I know it's an old sensor but I got it for $20 so I could do some prototyping with it.

Notes:

- laser project is ON
- light starts out blinking then goes solid green
- when not level light goes red
- RGB camera works but is a little choppy and sometimes shows tears in the picture.

freenect-glcplview output (snippet):

```
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 70] Expected 1748 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 70] Expected max 1748 data bytes, but got 1908. Dropping...
[Stream 70] Expected max 1748 data bytes, but got 1908. Dropping...
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
```

freenect-regview output (snippet)

```
[Stream 70] Invalid magic 2dc5
[Stream 70] Invalid magic aaf5
[Stream 70] Invalid magic dddb
[Stream 70] Invalid magic 9272
[Stream 70] Invalid magic 9873
[Stream 70] Invalid magic 9b8b
[Stream 70] Invalid magic 59eb
[Stream 70] Invalid magic 88f1
[Stream 70] Invalid magic 75ee
[Stream 70] Invalid magic ffff
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Lost 1 packets
[Stream 80] Lost 15244 total packets in 514 frames (29.657587 lppf)
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Expected 1908 data bytes, but got 948
[Stream 80] Invalid magic 3b46
[Stream 80] Lost 1 packets
```

Found this which gives me the idea that this may be a USB issue: [Regular receipt of undersized packet](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/84).

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the last post in the thread you linked states it's a USB speed issue, then says you need 20 MB/s to do depth and RGB, which means you **cannot** do it on a USB 1.0 port; you need 2.0 or 3.0.

See [this support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202875) on Apple's site for how to determine the speed of your USB ports. You didn't give the model of your computer, but if it's an older laptop you might have 1.0 ports.

Try checking your port speed and switch to a 2.0 port (or just a different 2.0 port) and see if you have the same issue.